# confusion with java method overloading

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, subclass, superclass

I'm currently working through a Java Book and i've started reading about inheritance and polymorphism.

I'm making a test program that stores animal information, and I want to overload the method that sets the animals size. The user knows the sizes of the dog, but no other animals, so sets animal size to 0 if it's not a dog, and for the dog, it uses its own setSize method with parameters.

However i've tried two methods of creating a dog, by creating an animal object and also by creating a dog object. I assumed that even though the testDog1 variable is of type Animal, it would still be able to overload methods from the Dog class as it is a dog object.

Could anyone please explain why testDog1 does not work but testDog2 does work?

```
public class Loader {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int dogSize = 100;

        Animal testDog1 = new Dog();
        testDog1.setSize(dogSize);

        Dog testDog2 = new Dog();
        testDog2.setSize(dogSize);

    }
}

public class Animal {

    public int size;

    public void setSize(){

        size = 0;
        System.out.println(size);

    }

}

public class Dog extends Animal {

    public void setSize(int dogSize){

        size = dogSize;
        System.out.println(size);

    }

}
```

Comment: I've made this argument before: use realistic examples. You're half-way there because you don't use names like A and B but actually try to model something real, but what then is an animal's "size" ? Length? Height? Does that include the tail? Its pretty meaningless, and modeling something meaningless is confusing.

Comment: this would be assuming that every instance of Animal is always an instance of Dog, which is not true.

Comment: From a design perspective, an Animal should not be able to have a size = 0 and you should not want to create an instance of Animal (its too generic right, hence why you are using inheritance to create specific types like Dog) - therefore Animal should be 'abstract'. If 'size' is a fundamental property of your model of Animals then have 'setSize' as an 'abstract' method (forces all subtypes to override it) and have it take the size 'int' an argument ie. you want overriding not overloading.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to refer to `testDog1` in your code, the compiler will consider it to be of class `Animal`. Meaning you can reassign it with an instance of `Cat` or `Bird` or anything else, where `setSize(int)` doesn't exist.

After `testDog1` was **declared** of type `Animal`, you need to comply with the contract of that class.

The fact that it **is** currently a `Dog` doesn't make the specific methods of `Dog` visible. You will probably learn about casting in the next chapter of the book, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Animal testDog1 = new Dog();
```

An instance of Dog would be created and assigned to the testDog1 variable only when you run the program. ie.) Runtime.

Compiler doesn't run the program or make hard and fast assumptions of what the nature of each statements or variables would be while checking for correctness.Had that been the case , the following stmt would have been a compile time error too.

```
Animal testDog = null;
testDog.setSize(); // How can you call setSize() on null right? for the same reason mentioned above.
```

Answer (score 0):

At compile time, all that the compiler knows is that in `testDog1` you will have a reference to an `Animal`. Since an `Animal` does not have a `setSize(int)`, the compiler cannot locate it and it fails.

It is important to know which operations are done at compile time (the compiler knows the type of the variable) and which one are done at runtime (the runtime knows the actual instance of the object).

Answer (score 0):

Your `testDog1` does not find `setSize(int dogSize)` method in `Animal` Class Hence it is a compilation error.
where as `testDog2` find `setSize(int dogSize)` method in `Dog` class and it will compile.

Answer (score 0):

testDog1 is an `Animal` object. Without casting it as a `Dog`, it doesn't know that `setSize(int)` exists.

`(Dog)testDog1.setSize(dogSize)` tells the compiler that it's actually a Dog.